# How to use Id of Clicked Input as an argument for c# method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, methods, input

I want to get Id of my input in C# language when I click it and use it as an argument in my event.

```
<input type="submit"  id="btn1" value ="Some Text" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick" />
```

I have searched for a long time looking for solution.

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code which use input id
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use HTML control with server side programming? Why not directly use ASPX controls?

Comment: are you implying that you have a WebBrowser control in a winform application that is required to send messages back and forth?

Comment: The client side control should be irrelevant to you on the server side. It's the action of the button itself that's important, not the button that generated that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is already passed as the argument `sender`. Simply cast it and access the property.

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" value="Some Text" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick" />
```

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var id = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputSubmit)sender).ID;

  // 'id' now contains the value "btn1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add runat server to your input, then you will be able to access it from your code behind`var blah = btn1.Id;`

I would recommend using the aspx controls:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click"></asp:Button>
```